# Export ado.net dataset into excel worksheets using softartisans Excelwriter

Tags: officewriter

I have a Ado.Net dataset that have three datatables let say Dataset name customer and tables are accounts, purchases and profile . i do like to export them using softartisans ExcelWriter to worksheets using templates

Example

```
 DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        myDataSet.Tables.Add("Customer");
        myDataSet.Tables.Add("Accounts");
        myDataSet.Tables.Add("Purchases");
        xlt.BindData(myDataSet,null , xlt.CreateDataBindingProperties());
```

I do like to export theses tables into seperate excel worksheets.

Answer (score 2):

The BindData method of OfficeWriter's ExcelTemplate object has a number of [overloads](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/ExcelTemplate.BindData).  The one that accepts a DataSet does not automatically import every DataTable in the DataSet, it only imports the first one.   If you want to use every DataTable in the DataSet, you should use the overload that takes a DataTable (see the [documentation](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/ExcelTemplate.BindData%28System.Data.DataTable,+String,+DataBindingProperties%29)).  For example:

```
//The 2nd parameter is the dataSource name that must correspond with the first 
//part of the datamarker in your template workbook (i.e. %%=Customer.FirstName)
xlt.BindData(DS.Tables["Customer"], "Customer", xlt.CreateDataBindingProperties());
```

You could also do something in a loop, like this:

```
foreach (DataTable table in myDataSet.Tables)
   {
     xlt.BindData(table, table.TableName, xlt.CreateDataBindingProperties());
   }
```